# Formulating Net Momentum of a 3-Body System

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

I'm struggling to formulate net axial and orbital momentum for >2 bodies.

The two-body problem involves a motorised disc attached to a freely-rotating one:

• disc1 is on a free axis

• disc2 is mounted to disc1 at some radius, by motor1

For simplicity 'motors' are considered intrinsic to the discs, and controllable for torque, acceleration or velocity etc.

Disc2's momentum is then just its moment times its rotational velocity

Disc1's momentum is given by adding the point-mass mr^2 of disc2 to its own moment, and multpilying by its velocity.

Thus when motor1 is engaged, i calculate two equal opposite momenta, summing to zero.  All good.

My difficulty arises when adding a third layer - disc3 mounted to disc2 by another motor in the same manner.

The system obviously conserves net momentum about the central free axis, no matter what permutation of the two motors are engaged, left coasting as free axes, or locked.  Yet with the third body present my simple approach to the two-body problem no longer suffices, due to the inter-reactions of disc3 changing radius relative to disc1.

I want to be able to plot symmetry of momentum and counter-momentum as before, showing their net cancellation, no matter which of the two motors is accelerated.

This simple problem has had me flummoxed for weeks - i suspect i need to modify the point-mass velocity of disc3 relative to disc1 as a function of its alternating prograde / retrograde motion, yet can't work out how to implement this either..

What is the correct procedure for stacking these inter-reacting momenta into a cancelling sum?